# openerp v7 get company name in invoice to contact

Tags: report, invoice, openerp-7

I am trying to have the invoice address created in the following way:

```
Company Name
Contact Name (= Partner of type 'invoice')
Company Street
Company CountryCode '-' Company Zip ' ' Company City
```

I tried by setting up to "customers" in OpenErp (mind you, it is Version 7) with one being the company (is_company is set to TRUE) and the other being the person (is_company is set to FALSE) to receive the invoice, inheriting the address from the company.

When I set up an invoice using the person as "customer", I can modify the invoice (using OpenOffice) to print out the address block in the following order:

```
Contact Name (= Partner of type 'invoice')
Company Name
Company Street
Company CountryCode '-' Company Zip ' ' Company City
```

Just by using the following code:

```
[[ (o.partner_id and o.partner_id.name) or '' ]]
[[ (o.partner_id and display_address(o.partner_id)) or '' ]]
```

The function display_address() obviously retrieves the 'contact_address' field which contains the company name.

But I don't seem to be able to directly retrieve the company name through the person-"customer".

If I set it up the other way around, with the company-"customer" as the invoice-addressee, I don't seem to be able to get to the person-"customer" at all. Although it is linked to the company-"customer" as one of the partners marked for 'invoices'.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this syntax:

```
[[ (o.partner_id.parent_id  and o.partner_id.parent_id.name) ]]
[[ (o.partner_id and o.partner_id.title and o.partner_id.title.name) or '' ]]  [[ (o.partner_id and o.partner_id.name) or '' ]]
[[ o.partner_id.street ]] 
[[ o.partner_id.zip ]] [[ o.partner_id.city ]]
[[ o.partner_id.country_id.name ]]
```

Greetings